# Explicit CPU placement in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, gpu, cpu, word-embedding

I found there are a piece of code in official model sample which confused me.

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  embedding = tf.get_variable(
      "embedding", [vocab_size, size], dtype=data_type())
  inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_.input_data)
```

Why using `tf.device("/cpu:0")` here? Except the case GPU memory leak, is there any other situation which we need to designate CPU operations explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to place the embedding matrix on a CPU is that `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` [isn't supported](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2502) on a GPU yet:

> So, given the basic word2vec example being bound to CPU (#514), we can
>   see that `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` doesn't work on GPU. Therefore, ops
>   that use `embedding_lookup` internally doesn't support GPU either (for
>   example, `nce_loss`).

This means that GPU placement of `embedding` variable will only lead to unnecessary transfer of data from the main memory to the GPU memory and vice versa. Hence, it would be more efficient to explicitly place the variable on a CPU.

Comment: Is there any other case need tf.device("/cpu:0")?

Comment: Yes, for example if one wants to do in-graph replication by splitting the computation across several GPUs: https://clindatsci.com/blog/2017/5/31/distributed-tensorflow That's why parameter servers (ps) are usually on CPU in tensorflow

Comment: To my understanding, using CPU is because the memory is usually larger than GPU memory, right?

Comment: It sound reasonable, yes. Word embedding matrix is often huge, while lookup operations are pretty cheap, so CPU placement is a good choice.

Comment: See it! Thanks, Maxim.